# Algorithm to set color of something, depending on its first character

Tags: objective-c, iphone, algorithm

I'm trying to differentiate between some background colors in my application, What's the biggest relation with this background ? Is that it has a text inside it,

So I thought of doing an algorithm that would do the following:

- Get first character of string
- Separate all characters into 5 groups (May get all characters count and divide by 5, then rage select ) .. For example :

  - From A -> E
  - From E -> I
  - From I -> N
  - From N -> S
  - From S -> Z

And from these groups, I can detect which group does the text belong to, and set a background color for each of these 5 groups,

For example, I have a text of "Hello", then it is from group #2, whom background color is #ff0000

I have a little issue here, is that if a character is not from a-z (maybe number or arabic character), then it would be a complete separate group (?)

Is there any better algorithm to apply for this case ? If not, I would like to know how to do the above algorithm using **Objective-C**

KEEP NOTED: I don't want a random COLOR !, I want it based on a set of colors that I have limited!

I found this : http://randomstringtocsscolor.com/, But it is a random generator.

**What i tried ?**

Using `NSString`'s `characterAtIndex:`, I can get the numeric value of a character, then easily compare them

```
NSString *text = @"Hello";
unichar firstCharValue = [text characterAtIndex:0];

if(firstCharValue >= 5){
  // background color Broup A
} else if(firstCharValue >= 10){
  // background color Group B
} else if(firstCharValue >= 15){
  // background color Group C
} else {
  // background color default (unknown characters)
}
```

**What's bad about this solution ?**

Not very convenient in the aspect of checking if number is bigger than or equal to X, and doesn't do very good with unknown characters, I'm interested to know more about a more convenient algorithm.

Comment: You can use `NSCharacterSet` if you want.

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want. You want a random color depending on first character ? or length of the word ?

Comment: @ThilinaChaminHewagama I want to set color for item depending on SET of colors I have in list, and BASED ON the first character of the string (I believe first character of the string because it is the strongest connection to generate a non-randomized color)

Comment: @Larme Please elaborate, What can i use it for ?

Comment: @Osa, that means "Hello", "How", "Hell" will get the same color ?

Comment: @ThilinaChaminHewagama Yeah, My whole point after all is that I want an algorithm to select a color for the text, based on this text ( so that I won't see it one time a color, and come back later and see it in another color )

Comment: @Osa, try my new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function which takes the text in and return a **random** color for the **word**.

```
-(UIColor *) randomColorFor:(NSString *) text{
    NSArray *colors = @[UIColor.blackColor, UIColor.redColor, UIColor.greenColor, UIColor.orangeColor];
    int code = (int)[[text uppercaseString] characterAtIndex:0];
    int index = code % colors.count;
    return colors[index];
}
```